# OKD 4.5 - How to upgrade cluster in restricted network

Tags: okd

I want to upgrade OKD cluster from 4.5.0-0.okd-2020-10-03-012432 to 4.5.0-0.okd-2020-10-15-235428
version in restricted network.

I could not find any steps on OKD documentation site. However, steps are present on OCP documentation site and looks straight forward.

Queries:

1. Is this scenario supported in OKD?
2. In below document at step #7, what could be corresponding step for OKD.

   https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.5/updating/updating-restricted-network-cluster.html#update-configuring-image-signature

   Where can I get image signature for OKD? Is this step valid for OKD?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

I did not perform steps mentioned in https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.5/updating/updating-restricted-network-cluster.html#update-configuring-image-signature

"--apply-release-image-signature" flag in "oc adm release mirror..." command creates configmap automatically.